# Where do I find documentation for the NSAccessibility protocol

Tags: macos, accessibility, accessibility-api

The client side documentation for the protocol is found https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibility#relationships (more precisely, the Swift API that must be implemented) but I can't seem to find any information on how one would interact with a client that implements this protocol.

Am I missing something? (obviously I am). Where do I find documentation on how, say, a screen reader, gets the information a client exposes.